# Receiving SMS Messages from Short Code Numbers?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

Firstly I would appreciate if someone can tell me if such a service already exists because it would save me a ton of time. A lot of the topics here discuss sending, I am trying to receive.

I am trying to design several web apps that interface with our vendors web portals to automate some daily tasks, while some of the vendors suggest or request MFA. A few vendors make it mandatory, so therefore I can't have my web app access the data behind the portal unless I can read the SMS message code that is being sent. While services like Twilio exist that allow me to receive SMS messages, they do not accept inbound messages from Short Code SMS. This appears to be true for a lot of providers. Google Voice is the only exception to this, but restricts me because I have to link an actual phone to my Google Voice account and I have to make a new account if I want more than 1 phone number. Not to mention I don't want to have random Google accounts not connected to a domain or organization.

Is my only recourse here to build or buy an inhouse SMS Gateway with a bunch of sim cards for every number I need?

Comment: Same issue here, trying to do that as well for my use case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54123942/9854223

Comment: @Clarence No good solutions exist. The easiest idea is to purchase an SMS Gateway device and use prepaid mobile numbers to handle SMS forwarding, in which case you can forward the text message to Twilio / API / Email. I am planning on developing a script to work with a raspberry pi 3 and multiple GSM modules to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the SMS Gateway box is the only way. Still you could consider using a Simbank.

With Simbank you will need to have less real GSM-channels in SMS-gateway (smaller SMS-gateway box, cheaper, less space etc.) still having many SIM-cards in the Simbank storage.

Setting up the whole thing to auto-change Sims around the clock (via software setup or via API) and assigning some minutes per Sim to stay in the air, will make it work as close as possible to keeping them all online 24/7. How smooth it will be depends on SIM-cards/GSM-channels ratio you have as  having 1 GSM-channel and 100 SIMcards will make it really slow.

So it's good idea to check in advance if SMS-Gateway manufacturer supports Simbank technology before making a deal.