# Twilio Inbound Messages showing as 'No Incoming Messages' even though SMS has been sent to that Twilio number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to use Twilio to create an automated test which includes a one-time-password (OTP) sent via SMS for my organization.

General Flow:

1. User signs up, inputting phone number
2. User receives OTP (from Nexmo's Verify) via SMS
3. User inputs the OTP received

The idea for me to automate this is to have my test script inputting the Twilio phone number, calling the Twilio SMS API (doc: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource), extracting the OTP from the message and inputting it into the application.

The issue here is that [no incoming messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kML0g.png) are being shown on my Twilio console.

I have also [configured the Twilio phone number to a TwiML Bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn4rC.png), whenever a message is received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response></Response>
```

I have tried this with both Malaysian `+60` and Australian `+61` Twilio phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not particularly familiar with Nexmo's Verify, but from a look at their product pages it suggests that verification messages will be sent from a short code. [Twilio numbers cannot receive messages from short codes](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181668-Can-Twilio-numbers-receive-SMS-from-a-short-code-). This is likely why you can't see any inbound messages for your number.